# Java EE REST Path levels to array

Tags: web-services, rest, jakarta-ee, jax-rs

I have to following URI which outputs categories and subcategories:

Pattern:

```
www.uri.com/webservice/category1/category2/category3/category4
```

Example:

```
www.uri.com/webservice/1/56/104/605
```

This URI can have none,one or more subcategories like in the example.
How do i get these parameters (1,56,104,605) in an array so i can check if each category is a subcategory of the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inject an `UriInfo` instance in your resource method and use the [`getPathParameters()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/core/UriInfo.html#getPathParameters%28%29)  or [`getPathSegments()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/core/UriInfo.html#getPathSegments%28%29) method:

```
@Path("category/{categoryIds:.+}/product/{productId}")
public ReturnType myMethod(@Context UriInfo uriInfo) {

    for (PathSegment pathSegment: uriInfo.getPathSegments()) {
        //do here what you want with the uriInfo
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks and if i want to add another resource at the end? like that: www.uri.com/webservice/1/56/104/605/product/1

Comment: My answer remains still valid... doesn't it?

Comment: yeah its valid. i think i haven't really realised the system of stack overflow :O sorry.

Comment: the answer is very helpful but i don´t know exactly how to realise this: www.uri.com/webservice/1/56/104/605/product/1. i want to add another resource to the end

Comment: Do you want a new Resource method or do you already have one, and you want to get access to the last parameters? Also I do not really understand why do you need all IDs passed in path: why not passing only the last subcategory, like `www.uri.com/webservice/605/product/1`?

Comment: i have one resource which is called category with the following path: @Path("category/{categoryId}/"). But in my application there should be as much sub category as you want. you can think about it like a folder. each folder has subfolders and files (in my case categories and products). i don´t know how the pattern of the @Path should look like in the product resource. Something like that: @Path("category/{categoryId}/{category2Id}/.../product/1")

Comment: Try the following: `@Path("category/{categoryIds:.+}/product/{productId}")`

Comment: thanks thats perfect! where can in find this syntax pattern information? this solved my problem!

Comment: The syntax is simple: after a colon you can specify a regex. If you do not use colon, it is considered a single path segment (until the next / character)

Comment: Google for "JAX-RS tutorial" in order to find more details about what is supported.